# WPF ListView & Converter

Tags: wpf, xaml, converters

I have a `ListView` with a `GridViewColumn` that has an image in it, it uses a converter to convert a `bool`  to a `ImageSource`. It was working perfectly for months and now it suddenly just shows a red dot instead of my image.

Converter:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{

  if ((bool)value)
    return new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Dionysus.Styling;component/Images/Actions-dialog-ok-apply-icon.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
  else return 
    null;

}
```

Xaml:

```
                    <GridViewColumn Header="">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=IsDelayedOrPreferred, Converter={StaticResource DelayConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
```

Result:

[image]

Has anyone seen this behaviour before or know what might have changed. The only recent changes that I made was upgrading to VS 2013 but all other `ListView`s with `Converter`s
are still working as expected.

Style:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">

    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>

    <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="ListView_Loaded"/>

</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,0"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" x:Key="ListViewStyle">


    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
        </Trigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFirst}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLastUnpaid}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSalmon"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF41B1E1"></Setter>
        </Trigger>

    </Style.Triggers>

    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>

</Style>
```

UPDATE:

I recently changed from a `ListView` to a `DataGrid` and then I see a little exclamation mark as if there is data validation errors on the `DataGrid`.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What does Snoop say? Maybe these dots are your images but with 1x1 size?

Comment: Hi,Did you apply CellTemplate in your ListView?

Comment: @icebat after finally being able to find that little image in Snoop, when I want to see the properties of that image it takes very long but is still population properties. Will let you know when i see the height and width. @Nisarg yes it is done exactly the same as my other `ListView`s whele I also have an image. @icebat even if i set the width and height to 30 the image remains the same.

Comment: Can you show me your style? And when your converter return null value,at that time it's showing red dot or in both case it's showing red dot?

Comment: @NisargChauhan see updated question for style, and it is only showing the dot on rows where it should show the image. Other rows are not showing anything like it should.

Comment: You use an image from another DLL (`Dionysus.Styling`). Might be that someone changed the image in the DLL and recompiled? Try digging with ILSpy to see what is the actual source (make sure you load the exact same DLL as your reference, i.e. same local path). Also, for debugging, change the converter to return a local image (from hard disk, absolute path) that you're sure what it is - so that we can rule-out a change in the source.

Comment: Please see updated question for new findings